# Anyone may suggest a temperature sensor technology that will work to a max of 200ºC?

Tags: sensor, measurement, temperature, instrumentation

Cheapest sensor technology as possible, up to +- 5ºC or 5% of accuracy. Better if it doesn't need complex (and costly) additional circuits.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are considered off-topic here. See the help page: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more info on what questions are acceptable.

Comment: Question edited to make it more appropriate. Please change if the meaning is not correct.

Comment: Sorry @I.Wolfe.

Comment: thx again Spehro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermocouple will be the cheapest **sensor** and the most rugged, not necessarily lowest system cost.

Platinum RTD will likely be the lowest system cost for small quantities and will be quite stable.

If there is high volume involved (eg. appliance applications), consider a silicon resistive sensor.

I would not recommend thermistors or semiconductor sensors in this temperature range.

Comment: Interesting... thermistors are the norm in 3d printer heads, which typically operate around 200-230 C depending on filament type.  But then they can also be prime examples of "seat of the pants" design.

Comment: thx Spehro, I will take a look at silicon resistive sensors.

Comment: I've checked DigiKey.  There is a fair number of thermistors rated for 200°C.  Some of them can be had for $2.50 in quantities of 100.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thermistors can be used over a wide range of temperatures, but not to measure a wide range of temperatures, if you get the distinction. The problem is that the resistance is wildly non-linear and varies greatly with temperature. This large variation makes them sensitive within a narrow range of interest, but difficult to handle for large temperature swings. A printer head temp should be held to narrow limits, so a thermistor is excellent for this purpose, but not so good if a wide temperature range needs to be measured accurately.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I have had bad experiences with the long-term stability and reliability of thermistors used at relatively high temperatures, despite being within ratings.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast a micro can easily handle a multi-part curve model provided the other half of the divider doesn't need to change, but the longetivity concern is interesting.

Comment: Sorry, but over wide ranges the sensitivity gets so low that you lose resolution and precision.